# Query to insert similar data from one table into another SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table named Item it has columns

```
ID, Code, Description, Cost, Quantity, Barcode, Pack, Bin
```

I have create another table named Stock with columns

```
ID, Code, Description
```

I would like to create either a trigger or stored procedure that automatically updates my stock table with only the columns  (ID,Code,Description) every time I create a new product in my Item table. I would this to happen when the user creates the product from the front end of the system once it updates the Item table it also updates the stock table .I have tried the script below and it keep telling me Invalid columns (Code, Description)

```
INSERT stock (Code, Description)
SELECT DISTINCT Code, Description
FROM Item
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT Code, Description FROM Item)
```

Kindly assist in solving this mystery because the columns exist in both tables

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Comment: @ricky i would say using `not exists` will have much performance impact if they are large tables and can take ages to run. I suggest u to use merge procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateStockDetails ON Item
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
    Stock 
    (
        Code,
        Description
    )
    SELECT 
        Code,
        Description
    FROM 
        INSERTED
    WHERE
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
       SELECT 
           Code,
           Description 
       FROM 
           Stock 
       WHERE 
           Stock.Code = INSERTED.Code
       AND 
           Stock.Description = INSERTED.Description
    )
END
```

Comment: Thank you Abhilash Really appreciate your kind assistance

Comment: @Ricky if the code is working for you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this.

`NOT EXISTS` can judge the row is or isn't exist on the subquery.

```
INSERT INTO 
    stock (Code, Description)
SELECT 
    Code, Description
FROM 
    Item
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS 
   (
       SELECT Code, Description FROM stock 
       WHERE 
            stock.Code = Item.Code
        AND 
            stock.Description = Item.Description
   )
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel Really appreciate your kind assistance

Answer (score 0):

This operation will be performed by a trigger, but please add your DBMS because body of it can be different for distinct DBMS.

Your query will be:

```
INSERT stock (Code, Description)
SELECT DISTINCT Code, Description
FROM item
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'stock' FROM stock where Stock.code = item.code
              and stock.description = item.description)
```

Comment: Thank you Joe Really appreciate your kind assistance